# Is there any Good homeschooling program that has curriculum based on Encyclopedia in USA?

Tags: homeschooling

I am not American citizen & I don't live in America. I am living in a Southeast Asian country, but I hate the education system there.

There are too much homework and lack of innovation. So I want my kids to learn American homeschooling program.

However American educational system may be too Western! & I don't like that. I want my kids to learn both Western + Eastern way of life / philosophy / knowledge.

Since the Encyclopedia (such as Wikipedia) mentions both Western + Eastern knowledge, I want my children to attend the homeschooling program that has curriculum based on Encyclopedia.

My kids can learn online through internet & they can do the test online as well. When they are 18 years old, they can come to America for continuous study.

So, my question is:

> Is there any Good homeschooling program that has curriculum based on
>   Encyclopedia in USA?

Comment: I don't think learning solely based on an encyclopedia would be an effective learning curriculum; encyclopedia teaches the 'what', but not really the 'why' or the 'how'.  Even for a history class (which is really what you could cover that way) you need interpretation and context beyond what you'd learn from an encyclopedia.

Comment: i mean the curriculum should include "why" & "how" into the encyclopedia. besides, i don't think encyclopedia only teach "what", but some "why" and "how" as well though not much.

Comment: I'm sure Joe will fall over from astonishment - I agree completely with him.  I would add that as an educational resource, Wikipedia is not reliable.  It is almost always pretty good, and fairly accurate. but "pretty good" and "fairly accurate" are not quite good enough.

Comment: Subjects like mathematics, science, etc will be the same (hopefully) wherever you are.  I really am not aware of the specifics of what is taught in various cultures, but I would think the major difference in American curriculum would be the American view on International History & current events as well as the focus on American History.   

Maybe you could look through a very mainstream standard lesson plan to see what you like.  This one gives them for all ages.  https://www.time4learning.com/scope-sequence/index.shtml

Answer (score 2):

While we teachers strive to eliminate bias, it still crops up in curriculum.  I feel like this is probably true everywhere.  If you want American (or, possibly UK for a bigger worldview) curriculum, you'll have to take the "good" with the "bad".  The nice thing about homeschooling, though, is that *you* can make sure that the desired Eastern philosophies and ways of life are incorporated.

So, choose a curriculum based on its academic credentials, then be engaged enough to overcome any undesired bias that crops up.

Comment: I disagree with the idea that UK presents a bigger worldview.  Different, yes.  But bigger?  I wonder if you're painting both UK and American schools with too broad a brush.

Comment: Hmmm. Perhaps a poor choice of words on my part. American curriculum tends to be extremely centered on America. This is changing, slowly, but as an educator for over a decade, I assure you the bias most certainly exists. When comparing curriculum, I find that the UK stuff has less cultural bias than US curriculum. I can easily be wrong though. One of the problems with bias is that you generally don't notice it unless you work at it, so my perception could be simply because I don't recognize UK-centric bias.